# Is there a way to create a new thread with space allocated for that thread, but defer the execution in c++11?

Tags: c++11, threadpool

Let's say i want to create a thread, I want the necessary spaces allocated for the thread, however, i'd like to defer launching that thread.
I'm working on a threadpool, so i'd like to have some threads ready(but not running) before I start the threadpool. 
Is there a way to do so in C++11?

Answer (score 0):

You could have all the threads wait on a semaphore as soon as they start up.  And then you can just signal them when it's time for them to actually start running.

Comment: I'm asking a way to not launch the thread after space allocated for it. Waiting on a signal or whatever is still counting as started.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to the "Thread Pool / Task" behavior present in a number of languages (and probably several C++ libraries like boost). A Thread Pool has one or more threads, and can queue Tasks. When it doesn't have tasks, a Thread Pool just waits for input. They can also, as implied, queue up tasks if the threads are busy.